# Sharing an image on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to share an image from my webpage to Facebook.

I've looked at Facebook's dev pages, and it you need to add meta data to your page - you may specify an image - this will then be shared.

The problem is I have a number of images on my page.

Is it possible to share specific images - where should I be looking in the api?

Comment: You’ll need individual URLs holding the meta data, one for each image. (You can redirect human users following those links from Facebook back to the “main” page if you want. Be aware however, that likes and shares for those URLs will be counted individually as well.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of images and want to select a particular one during sharing, then you can add multiple `og:image` tags - one for each image.

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://image1.jpg">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://image2.jpg">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://image3.jpg">
  ...
```

Once you do this, on sharing, the user will be able to select from one of these images.

Also after you add these tags, make sure that you force a re-scrape to update your OG object: pop your url into the [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and 'Fetch new scrape information'.